# Delete suffix from multiple lines of different lengths in vim

Tags: vim

With the help of vim I want to convert this file

```
aaaaaaaaaaaa.xxx()
bbbbbbbbbbbbbbb.xxx()
cc.xxx()
ddddddddd.xxx()
eeeeeee.xxx()
fffff.xxx()
```

into this file

```
aaaaaaaaaaaa
bbbbbbbbbbbbbbb
cc
ddddddddd
eeeeeee
fffff
```

A search/replace command like

```
:%s/.xxx()//g
```

would do the job. I wonder if there are better and more elegant options?

Comment: Your solution seems pretty elegant to me.

Comment: Is there a problem with the current solution?

Comment: There is no problem with the search/replace command. I want to extend my editing skills in vim and searching for alternative approaches.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe use `:normal`

```
:%norm f.D
```

For more information see:

```
:h :norm
```

Comment: You can get the same results with `:%s/\..*`

Answer (score 4):

This substitution works only by chance: the `.` matches *any character* and thus appears to work in your case because `.` is matched by `.` as if you actually did that purposefully. You must escape the `.` to match a regular `.`:

```
:%s/\.xxx()//g
```

Since there's only one occurrence of your search pattern on each line you can safely leave out the `g` flag.

```
:%s/\.xxx()//
```

And you can even leave out the two last slashes:

```
:%s/\.xxx()
```

If that's not elegant, I don't know what is.

But, there's always another way. Something like this, for example:

```
:%norm $F.D
```

Comment: @zdd, and often more intuitive than regular expressions.

Comment: +1 I didn't see your normal command. I wouldn't have posted if I had.

Answer (score 1):

your process by VIM for string replacement is better, but i have another solution to replace it.

Its useful, if you want to replace across the multiple files.

```
#grep -rl "string1" * -R | xargs sed -i 's/string1/string2/g'
```

Here above command is combination of  'grep' and 'sed'

**grep :** Command will search for "string1" and returns file-name where string1 found

**sed :** will replace the "string1" to "string2"

**string1 :** old string
**string2 :** New string

Hope its useful and faster for multiple file string replacement.

Reference Link : http://tarunlinux.blogspot.in/2014/02/linux-replace-string-in-multiple-files.html

Answer (score 1):

If there is no extra dot in text line, you can try

```
%s/\..*$//g
```

Answer (score 0):

I would do it like this:

```
qaf.Dj0q@6@a
```

It is slightly shorter than yours, possibly slower if your file has many lines that need to be changed. Mine is more general: you can apply almost anything you can think of with a macro.